# How run SharePoint PowerShell Script from a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, form

I have this PowerShell script which creates a SharePoint page with content without logging into the application which is intended for general users to manage content.

The script takes in 5 parameters as per user input. How can I implement this in a form so that users can access it out of the server but not exposed to the script itself?

```
$PageLayoutUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx"  
$PageName = "Pages/PageSix.aspx"  
$pagecontent = [string]$_.PageContent
# Get site object and create publishing site object  
$SPSite = Get-SPSite("http://10.xxx.xx.xx:6060")  
$PublishingSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($SPSite)  
# Get web object and create publishing web object  
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://10.xxx.xx.xx:6060"  
$PublishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($SPWeb)  
$LayoutsColl = $PublishingSite.GetPageLayouts($False)
# Get the page layout object and create Publishing Page based on it  
$SPPageLayout = $LayoutsColl[$PageLayoutUrl]  
$Page = $PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage("PageSix.aspx", $SPPageLayout)  
$Page.Title = "This is page six" 
    Write-Host "Creating $pagetitle"
    $Page.ListItem["Page Content"] = "PAGE SIX
                             TESTING 123 SENTENCE HERE. 
                             adipiscing elit adipiscing elit adipiscing adipiscing elit 
                            Body page content enter here. Body page content enter here.
                             Body page content enter here."
$Page.Update();  
$Page.CheckIn("Page Created")  
$Page.ListItem.File.Publish("Page Checked in and Publishing Completed")
```